# Modal loading dynamic content not working

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I am developing an app which requires options like view,So for viewing details I am using bootstrap modal to show the dynamic details,but the modal is not firing up.

**My button**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm view" data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-title="{{$value->title}}" data-status="{{$value->status}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"> Preview</i>
                  </a>
```

**My modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="viewM" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width:60%;">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Preview</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="preview" style="padding: 40px;">
    </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span> Close
        </button>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My jquery**

```
$('a.view').click(function()
                  {
                    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    var url = 'receiveReprt';

                     $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) 
                     {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#preview").html(data.content);
                        $('#viewM').modal({show:true});    
                     });      
                  });
```

**Url function**

```
public function receiveReprt($id)
    {
        $reprt = shareReport::select('content')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
        return $reprt;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting your data in the `console.log` line? Is the $.get going to the right URL?

Comment: it's not bringing any data

Comment: Please post the contents of your controller action that is supposed to return the data

Comment: @JPark it's a text file... i've done this before but don't know why it's not working this time. i even did copy and paste and it doesn't seem to respond when i click the button but other modals are working.

Comment: It might be that your click event is not firing, try using `$('a.view').on('click', function() {})` instead.

Comment: @JPark tried that not working..... what can be the cause of data-id not showing,cos i inspect the modal and found out data-id is blank for all the modal

Comment: That means that `id` is missing from `$value` then. You can print out your variable to verify its contents `{{ dd($value) }}`.

Comment: @JPark yes it's missing.... guess it's got to do with my db but that's not why the modal is not popping up

Comment: Well, the modal is not popping up because your `$.get` function fails (probably due to a 404 from the missing id). You can chain the function call with `.fail(function() { })` to try and catch it. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ for more info.

Comment: @JPark that is not the issue cos i have fixed the missing Id bug but it is still not popping.... tried normal modal and it popped up without the dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors in your browser log? My guess at this point is that you are dealing with a javascript error, possibly due to `data.content` (e.g. if it's not object), which kills the script execution.

If this is the case, and `data` is not an object as I suspect, you can convert to one (assuming it's JSON of course):

```
$.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) 
{
    console.log(data);
    $("#preview").html(data.content);
    $('#viewM').modal({show:true});    
}, "json");
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + '/' + id,
    method: "get",
    success: function (data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);

        $("#preview").html(json.content);
        $('#viewM').modal({show:true}); 
    }
});
```